# Visual Studio - How to hide NuGet updates for AspNetCore 6.0.0

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

Currently I'm using AspNetCore 5.0.11 and Visual Studio 16.11.5.

Yesterday they have released .NET 6.0.0. and NuGet is showing me now to update AspNetCore and EntityFrameworkCore to version 6.0.0.

[image: Nuget-Packages]

My target framework ist `net5.0`:

[image: Target-Framework]

And I also haven't installed any .NET 6.0.0 runtime:

[image: dotnet --info]

I **don't** want to use 6.0.0 at the moment - it is just release one day ago... I know that I can select the newest 5.0.12 from the version list manually, but I'm maybe missing other important package updates, because 6.0.0 is filling up the list.

How can I hide the 6.0.0 NuGet updates? Instead it should show me only the 5.0.12 NuGet-updates for my currently used target-framework.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Note that there's no requirement that you need to use the 6.0 runtime to run any package that is named 6.0. It's just a convention that the packages released now are linked to the 6.0 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this issue and with net7 being in release candidate, we now have version 7 of the AspNetCore packages which are dependent on net7.

The only workaround I have now is to make them auto update to a specific major version by using wildcard. Eg,

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.*" />
```

The packages will still be shown in the package manager, but on every Rebuild, VS will attempt to restore the latest version 5.0.x of the packages.